# Programmatically set width of HTML element at runtime in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on a directive in an AngularJS project. In this directive, I **HAVE** to programmatically set the width of an HTML element at runtime. However, I am not having any success in doing so. Currently, my directive looks like this:

[**My Plunkr Is Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/6C2psZ39v0JMMN887qXI?p=preview)

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function () {
  return {
    restrict:'E',
    transclude: true,
    templateUrl: 'my-directive.html',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var inputField = element.find('input');
            scope.width = inputField[0].offsetWidth;      

            scope.err1 = 'none';
            try {
            var testDiv = element.find('#test-name');
            element(testDiv).css('width', (scope.width + 'px'));
            } catch (e1) {
              scope.err1 = e1.message;
            }

            scope.err2 = 'none';
            try {
              var testDiv = element.find('.test-class');
              element(testDiv).css('width', '500px');

            } catch (e2) {
              scope.err2 = e2.message;
            }
    },
    controller: function ($scope) {
    }
  };
});
```

As [the plunkr shows](http://plnkr.co/edit/6C2psZ39v0JMMN887qXI?p=preview), I get a runtime error when I attempt to programmatically set the width of my div. I do not understand what I'm doing wrong. Can somebody please show me what I'm doing wrong? I need to figure out how to set the width at runtime in either the link or controller function. Once again, I have to do this programmatically. I *cannot* add a width to the scope and bind the UI to it.

Comment: `testDiv.css('width', (scope.width + 'px'));` and `testDiv.css('width', '500px');
   `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go.

[Your new plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/E7BzbdDMWGVXKOzfCchf?p=preview)

you have a few issues. First off there isn't an element with `id` `test-name` - you had the `name` set, not the `ID`.

Also, `find()` will not work, use `children()` instead - your example wasn't actually finding the element, hence getting the error you had.

New directive (removed your error stuff for clarity) - you can change/remove the second scope.width just to see it working

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
myApp.directive('myDirective', function () {
  return {
    restrict:'E',
    transclude: true,
    templateUrl: 'my-directive.html',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {


      var inputField = element.find('input');
      var name = element.children('#test-name');
       scope.width = inputField[0].offsetWidth; 

       scope.width = inputField[0].offsetWidth /3; // To test 

      angular.element(name).css('background-color', 'orange');
      angular.element(name).css('width', (scope.width + 'px'));
    }
  };
});
```

your new template with some CSS removed, and the ID of the test-name set - instead of the name attribute

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="my-directive.html">
      <div style="width:100%">
        <div id="test-name">Hello</div>
        <input type="text" style="width:100%;" />
        <br /><br />
        <div>Width: {{width}}</div>
        <div>Error #1: {{err1}}</div>
        <div>Error #2: {{err2}}</div>
      </div>
    </script>
```